# cursor:pointer doesn't work on a transparent trigger overlay?

Tags: pointers, overlay, internet-explorer-10, transparent

I have a problem with the cursor in IE10 any ideas? It doesn't appear at all in IE10.

http://jsfiddle.net/alexnode/y4y4A/8/

```
<div id="bgmbutton1">
        <img id="button1"  src="http://translationgames.org/images/button1overlay.png" alt="Translation games"> 
      <img id="obutton1"  src="http://translationgames.org/images/button1.png" alt="Translation games">
      <div id="otrigger1" class="button" data-case="translation"></div> 
    </div>
```

css

```
#bgmbutton1{position: fixed;
    left: 2%;
    top: 5%;
    }
#button1 {width: 25%;}
#obutton1 {width: 25%;position: absolute;top:0;left:0;}
#otrigger1 {background:rgba(0,0,0,0); height:100%; width:100%; position: absolute; left: 0; top: 0; cursor: pointer; z-index:5000;}
```

Comment: cursor:pointer doesn't appear at all in IE10 while it appears in all other browsers. Any ideas ?

Comment: in my #otrigger i have cursor:pointer but it doesn't work in IE10. The JSfiddle is a bit weird with the pointer but

Comment: you can see the problem here http://translationgames.org/template.html

Comment: i haven't correct the widths for IE9 yet so please don't try with it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your approach seems to be overcomplicating things just a bit. Might I suggest a slightly more straight-forward approach instead. I've tested this to ensure it works fine in IE.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <title>Hover-Fading Buttons</title>
        <style>
            .button {
                width: 100px;
                height: 100px;
                display: block;
                position: relative;
            }
            .button img {
                border: 0;
                width: 100%;
                top: 0; left: 0;
                position: absolute;
                transition: opacity .5s;
            }
            .button:hover .default {
                opacity: 0;
            }
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <a class="button" href="#">
            <img class="overlay" src="http://translationgames.org/images/button1overlay.png" alt="Translation games">
            <img class="default" src="http://translationgames.org/images/button1.png" alt="Translation games">
        </a>
    </body>
</html>
```

As you can see, this does rely on the `transition` and `opacity` properties. If you require support for older browsers, you could go back to a JavaScript approach using jQuery:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <title>Hover-Fading Buttons</title>
        <style>
            .button {
                width: 100px;
                height: 100px;
                display: block;
                position: relative;
            }
            .button img {
                border: 0;
                width: 100%;
                top: 0; left: 0;
                position: absolute;
            }
        </style>
        <script src="http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jQuery/jquery-1.10.1.js"></script>
        <script>
            $(function () {
                $(document).on("mouseover mouseout", ".button", function () {
                    $(this).find(".default").stop().fadeToggle(300);
                });
            });
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <a class="button" href="#">
            <img class="overlay" src="http://translationgames.org/images/button1overlay.png" alt="Translation games">
            <img class="default" src="http://translationgames.org/images/button1.png" alt="Translation games">
        </a>
    </body>
</html>
```

I hope this helps you.

Comment: I am so sorry but I won't have time to check this out until next weekend. The only thing that I see as a bit of a problem is that I did all this in order to have my buttons scaling with %. I don't remember why but I stuck with css doing it with %. I have to check it out next Saturday.

Comment: I was searching to find a bug or something online regarding having a transparent div trigger with cursor:pointer in IE but i didn't find anything. The transparency is not a problem. i made the button soild to test and still didn't work, i added z-index to all children and still didn't work. I was really puzzled.

Comment: @alexnode You should be able to change `.button` to have `%` based dimensions.